# Using maxuploadtarget in Node Window Console

Tags: bitcoin-core, bandwidth

Complete first-timer to setting up my own node here... I’ve got as far as downloading and syncing the node (on Windows PC), getting my router and anti-virus ports sorted, but want to limit my upload/download capacity for a number of reasons.

I’m trying to follow the instructions from bitcoin.org by typing in `-maxuploadtarget=<MiB per day>` Or `-maxconnections=<num>` into the Node Window Console.

I keep getting the error “Method not found” despite trying a number of different ways of typing in the command.  Do I include the “-“, do I include the “< >”, do I include “Mib”, etc.

Can someone please help what exactly I should type in for a medium quality broadband without drawing too much attention (e.g. 500 MiB?).

Thanks so much and look forward to joining the BTC network.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make changes in bitcoin.conf file

[image: bitcoin.conf]

[Bitcoin Core Config Generator (compatible with Bitcoin Core 0.20)](https://jlopp.github.io/bitcoin-core-config-generator/#config=eyJuZXR3b3JrIjp7Im1heGNvbm5lY3Rpb25zIjo1MCwibWF4cmVjZWl2ZWJ1ZmZlciI6NDAwMCwibWF4c2VuZGJ1ZmZlciI6ODAwLCJtYXh1cGxvYWR0YXJnZXQiOjUwMH19)